# pkgng shows missing dependency which is allready installed

Tags: dependencies, dependency-management, freebsd

I was trying to upgrade Imagemagick-nox11-6.9.4.3 (from 6.9.4.1) on my FreeBSD server (10.3 x64) from package via pkgng and got an error:

```
# pkg add --force ImageMagick-nox11-6.9.4.3,1.txz
[litte-j-server.com] Installing ImageMagick-nox11-6.9.4.3,1...
package ImageMagick-nox11 is already installed, forced install
pkg: Missing dependency 'perl5'

Failed to install the following 1 package(s): ImageMagick-nox11-6.9.4.3,1.txz
```

I was pretty surprised since it is production server with huge ammount of perl code. So, I've searched for it via pkgng - and it said perl5 is already installed:

```
# pkg info|grep perl5
perl5.20-5.20.2                Practical Extraction and Report Language
```

Package was downloaded from [pkg.freebsd.org](http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/latest/All/) since I should only use local network on that server. Then I'd become crazy and turned on the Internet on that server and moved on with pkg install:

```
# pkg install ImageMagick-nox11-6.9.4.3,1.txz 
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Updating database digests format: 100%
pkg: ImageMagick-nox11 has a missing dependency: perl5
pkg: ImageMagick-nox11 has a missing dependency: perl5
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The following 1 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be UPGRADED:
    ImageMagick-nox11: 6.9.4.1,1 -> 6.9.4.3,1

The process will require 17 KiB more space.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[litte-j-server.com] [1/1] Upgrading ImageMagick-nox11 from 6.9.4.1,1 to 6.9.4.3,1...
[litte-j-server.com] [1/1] Extracting ImageMagick-nox11-6.9.4.3,1: 100%
```

So, it was upgraded (and FreeBSD even said about perl5 dependency) - but if I try to make `pkg add --force` again, it shows same "Missing dependency".

Why does it show that? What should I do to fix it? Is it okay that pkgng installed package, but still saying that dependency is missing (could I crash something)?

P.S. I didnt find any 'pkg' or 'pkgng' tags here, sorry if I did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Although perl 5.20 is clearly installed on the server, it was installed from a package called `perl5.20` and not `perl5`. The latter picks up the latest approved version of perl 5. Possibly when the server was originally built, the admin decided that they needed 5.20 before the FreeBSD maintainers updated the `perl5` tag.

Both `pkg add` and `pkg install` have the `-M` option (aka `--accept-missing` and `--ignore-missing` respectively) to ignore missing dependencies. Try:

```
pkg add --force --accept-missing ImageMagick-nox11-6.9.4.3,1.txz
```

See [the manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-add) for more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. Yes, I've allready installed it with `-M` key, but I'm pretty scared about if I have missed some dependencies and some of ImageMagick functions doesn't work.

One more thing: when I've installed it with `--accept-missing` option it said that I don't even have `ghostscript9-agpl-base`, which is allready installed too (as I think, same situation as you wrote)